# Moment Display Birthdate Relative to Current Days DAYOFYEAR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

I am using `moment()` in my Angular app and I need to display the Birthdays (irrespective of the year) relative to the current days of the week. My server will send a list of birthdates coming up for this week in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and I want this to be shown like this (considering today's date is 2 March 2017):

```
BirthDate  - Display it to this year's day of the week
2014-03-01 - Yesterday
2016-03-02 - Today
2015-03-03 - Tomorrow
2014-03-04 - Saturday
etc...
```

In my Angular 1.5 view, I can send the data to a `dayCheck` function like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="person in birthdays">
  Name: {{person.name}} <br>
  When: {{vm.dayCheck(person.date)}}
</p>

function dayCheck(date) {
   return moment(date).format('DD'); // ?? How can I return the days relative to user's day from this year??
}
```

**My Answer:**

This is what I have come up with since I posted the question. It doesn't look elegant and I am sure there is a better what to do this. But the working code I have to resolve this is:

```js
function dayCheck(date) {
    var returnData = '';
    var birthDayDate = moment(date).format('DD');
    if (birthDayDate == moment().format('DD')) {
        var returnData = 'Today';
    }
    else if (birthDayDate == moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('DD')) {
        var returnData = 'Yesterday';
    }
    else if (birthDayDate == moment().add(1, 'days').format('DD')) {
        var returnData = 'Tomorrow';
    }
    else {
        var momentDate = moment(date);
        var month = momentDate.format('MM');
        var date  = momentDate.format('DD');
        var currentMonth = moment().format('MM');
        if (currentMonth == 12 && month == 1) {
            var year = moment().add(1, "years").year();
        }
        else if (currentMonth == 1 && month == 12) {
            var year = moment().subtract(1, "years").year();
        }
        else {
            var year = moment().year();
        }
        var dateFormat = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
        var returnData = moment(dateFormat).format('dddd');
    }
    return returnData;
}
```

Please do let me know if there is a better, elegant way to do the above. I also suspect the above will fail if the Birthday was on the 29th Feb of a leap year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use moment [`calendar()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/). To customize the format see [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/calendar/). Here a working example:

```js
var input = ['2014-03-01',
'2016-03-02',
'2015-03-03',
'2014-03-04'];

function dayCheck(date) {
  var thisYear = moment().year();
  var mom = moment(date).year(thisYear);
  return mom.calendar(null, {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
}

for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  console.log(dayCheck(input[i]));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh man! That is fantastic!!! Exactly what I was after. My method was like Lord of the Rings and yours is so brief and perfect! Thank you so much @VincenzoC!!

Comment: Just to confirm, this should work if the date was from Leap Year like 29-Feb-16 or if the date of Jan / Dec, etc.. right.

Comment: Okay, from the testing it appears 29th Feb of leap years will be considered as 1st March if that year is not a leap year.

Comment: I'm glad that my answer helped you. I did not have enough time to test it for leap years, does it provide the right output? What is the expected result for these cases?

Comment: When the date was 29th feb of a leap year, it shows the day for 1st March as the output. As a test, I changed my computer date to 24 feb and then it was showing the 29th Feb date as "Wednesday" which is actually the 1st March for this year. I think that is the desired output in such cases. So all good.

Comment: Ok, perfect! :)

Comment: @Neel—if you attempt to create a date using an invalid date string like "2017-02-29" (but not with values like `new Date(2017,1,29)`) the result **should** be an invalid date.

Comment: @RobG. You're right. But in that case, I think the `sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'` will show. However when I tried the leap year test before, I tried a valid date as 2016-02-29 when it showed the day for 1st March.

Comment: @Neel—I see your dilemma: what to do for birthdays on 29 Feb in non-leap years. Different jurisdictions have different rules: some go to 28 Feb, some to 1 Mar, same for personal preferences. There is no right or wrong answer which way to go.

Comment: @RobG You are absolutely right about how some people might prefer 28 Feb instead of 1 Mar for birthdays that fall on 29 Feb. However, in my application that scenario is something I can safely overlook as long as the result shows either of them. But yeah, users who have preference on 28 Feb will not be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, as not everyone uses moment.js, without a library it just needs a couple of simple functions to parse the strings, get day names, etc.:

```js
var myLib = {date: {
  // If notStrict is true, don't check for a valid date
  parseISOLocal: function (s, notStrict) {
    var b = s.split(/\D/);
    var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
    return notStrict || (d && d.getMonth() == b[1])? d : new Date(NaN);
  },

  daysDiff: function (a, b) {
    var diff = new Date(a).setHours(12,0,0,0) - new Date(b).setHours(12,0,0,0) ;
    return Math.round(diff/8.64e7);
  },

  dayName: function (d) {
    return d.toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday:'long'});
  }
}};

['2014-03-01','2016-03-02','2015-03-03','2010-03-04','2007-03-05',
 '1914-03-06','1987-03-07','1800-03-08','1991-03-24','2004-01-04',
 '2000-02-29'].forEach(function(s) {
  s = s.replace(/^\d{4}/,new Date().getFullYear());
  var d = myLib.date.parseISOLocal(s, true);
  var diff = myLib.date.daysDiff(d, new Date());
  if (diff > 7 || diff < -7) msg = d.toLocaleString(undefined,{day:'numeric',month:'long'});
  else if (diff <  -1) msg = 'Last ' + myLib.date.dayName(d);
  else if (diff == -1) msg = 'Yesterday (' + myLib.date.dayName(d) + ')';
  else if (diff ==  0) msg = 'Today';
  else if (diff ==  1) msg = 'Tomorrow (' + myLib.date.dayName(d) + ')';
  else                 msg = 'Next ' + myLib.date.dayName(d);
  console.log(d.toLocaleString(undefined,{day:'numeric', month:'short', year:'numeric'})
              + ' : ' + msg);
})
```

Dealing with 29 Feb is not easy, this just lets it roll over to 1 March, which may not suit everyone.

Comment: Thank you @RobG These functions will certainly help without moment.js. A very good alternative solution.